# Streamreader only return "System.IO.StreamReader"

Tags: c#, .net

I want text from a `.text` file into a listbox.

When I try to paste a `.text` file in to a listbox with the `StreamReader`, the `StreamReader` don't give me the text what is inside of the file. It gives me `System.IO.StreamReader` (10 times) back as result. So:

```
System.IO.StreamReader
System.IO.StreamReader
System.IO.StreamReader
```

But in the `.text` file I have this:

```
booking 1
booking 2
booking 3
booking 4
booking 5
booking 6
booking 7
booking 8
booking 9
booking 10
```

This is my code:

```
int count = 0;
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"D:\school\periode 2\software\week6\BookingSystem\BookingSystem\booking.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    lbCurrentBookings.Items.Add(file);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to properly dispose `StreamReader`. Also, instead of checking for null, you could utilize `StreamReader.EndOfStream` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lbCurrentBookings.Items.Add(file);
```

should be

```
lbCurrentBookings.Items.Add(line);
```

As commented by Flydog57 below:

When you see a string containing a class name like that, it nearly always means that you used a instance of that class as if it was a string. Many APIs can take either a string or an object. In the latter case, they call `ToString()` on the object. The default `object.ToString()` returns the class name. So, when you passed in the file variable, the `ListBox` code used the `Add(object someObject)` overload and just called `ToString` on what was passed

Comment: @jDoe Instead of thanks, you could just click on the checkmark next to the post to accept it as the answer that helped you.

Comment: @jdoe: When you see a string containing a class name like that, it nearly always means that you used a instance of that class as if it was a string.  Many APIs can take either a string or an `object`.  In the latter case, they call `ToString()` on the object.  The default `object.ToString()` returns the class name.  So, when you passed in the `file` variable, the `ListBox` code used the `Add(object someObject)` overload and just called `ToString` on what was passed

Comment: @Flydog57 - useful extra info that I should have probably added for clarification.